# Debian 9 I am getting "N: Skipping acquire of configured file..." when updating

Tags: debian, cups, printer

I have recently been getting the following message when updating. The

> ```
> N: Skipping acquire of configured file...
> ```

is concerning me. I have looked around to see if there was a solution, but could not find anything.

The `hl2270dw` is a Brother printer I use with success. Any information to get rid of this is appreciated.

```
[doy@sandbar ~]$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for doy: 
Hit:1 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.windscribe.com/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-cupswrapperhl2270dw/Packages' as repository 'https://repo.windscribe.com/debian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'cupswrapperhl2270dw'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-cupswrapperhl2270dw/Packages' as repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'cupswrapperhl2270dw'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-cupswrapperhl2270dw/Packages' as repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'cupswrapperhl2270dw'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-cupswrapperhl2270dw/Packages' as repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'cupswrapperhl2270dw'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-cupswrapperhl2270dw/Packages' as repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'cupswrapperhl2270dw'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-cupswrapperhl2270dw/Packages' as repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'cupswrapperhl2270dw'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-cupswrapperhl2270dw/Packages' as repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'cupswrapperhl2270dw'
```

EDIT (20200220):

```
[doy@sandbar ~]$ sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
cupswrapperhl2270dw


[doy@sandbar ~]$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list 
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20180714-10:25]/ stretch main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20180714-10:25]/ stretch main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib


[doy@sandbar ~]$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
# deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
#deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
deb https://repo.windscribe.com/debian stretch main
deb https://repo.windscribe.com/debian stretch main
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. You can [**accept** the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have executed the following command (by mistake):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture cupswrapperhl2270dw
```

It is not a valid architecture, you need to remove it:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture cupswrapperhl2270dw
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

[Debian:Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)